# What are shear lugs? (Piping supporting)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, piping

There is a course I'm following regarding Piping Design & Engineering. In a section about 'supporting' they talk about 'Shear lugs' but nowhere is there an explanation about what shear lugs actually are. Searched on google as well and didn't find anything helpful.

Anyone knows what shear lugs are and what they are used for?

Comment: Did you ask the person giving the course?

Comment: https://pipingtech.com/resources/faqs/when-are-shear-lugs-required-on-pipe-supports/

Comment: https://www.asdipsoft.com/shear-lug-design-overview-of-the-aci-provisions/

Answer (score 1):

They are lugs -- protrusions -- used to handle shear forces.

Ordinary supports handle weight (vertical) and bending forces. A car on bridge puts weight on the bridge, and bends the beams between the supports.

Sometimes there is also sideways or lengthways support required. a bridge is pushed in from the end, or pushed over from the side. That puts a sideways or lengthways force on the support. If there is no resistance, the support will just slide.

With pipes in particular, dynamic forces at bends will make the pipe want to move sideways or lengthways. To resist these movements, lugs are added to the pipe. The lugs engage with the supports to prevent shear movements.

"Lugs" are used for other purposes in mechanical engineering: to prevent rotation, or to lock moving components. "Shear Lugs" in Civil Engineering are used to prevent objects sliding off of their supports.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification David. I understand it now.